# Joomla Plugin inject Javascript snippet into all pages

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm trying to write a Joomla plugin that injects a small javascript code into all pages for distribution to others. but everything I have read says I should do it using the `$doc = JFactory::getDocument();` but I can't get it to work.

This is the code I'm trying to use and Joomla says everything is ok with it but once activated if I go to the homepage of my site my snippet of javascript is not being added to the source of the page.

Current Code:

bwai.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.0" type="plugin" group="system" method="upgrade">
    <name>Beacon Web Analytics Intergration for Joomla</name>
    <creationDate>June 2018</creationDate>
    <author>Beaconsoft Limited</author>
    <authorEmail>contact@thisisbeaon.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>https://www.thisisbeacon.com</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Beaconsoft Limited 2018</copyright>
    <license>BSD new</license>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>This plugin enables the Beacon Web Analytics Intelligence to run on your site, this information will not be saved unless you have an account for Beacon.</description>

    <files folder="site">
        <filename plugin="bwai">index.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <administration>
    </administration>
</extension>
```

index.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('No direct access');
die("hello");
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgSystemCustomhead extends JPlugin{
    function onBeforeCompileHead() {
        die("hello hello");
        /*if (JFactory::getApplication()->isAdmin()){
            return true;
        }*/
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $doc->addScriptDeclaration('
            (function(a, d, w){
                var h= d.getElementsByTagName(a[0])[0]; var s= d.createElement(a[1]);
                s.setAttribute("type", a[2]); s.setAttribute("src", a[3]); s.setAttribute(a[4], true); s.setAttribute(a[5], a[6]); h.appendChild(s);
            })(["head", "script", "text/javascript", "//tracker.thisisbeacon.com/tracker/", "async", "rel", "preload"], document, window);

        ', 'text/javascript'); 
    }
}
?>
```

All I want to do is have a small plugin people can install that adds our tracking javascript snippet code to all pages on the front end of a Joomla site.

Adding `exit('hello hello');` to the top of the function i have also tried adding `die("hello");` to the top of the file under the defined or die statement it does not execute but then Joomla reports the extension as active, as you can see above
[image: Joomlad Plugins][image: Plugin Settings page in Joomla]

Comment: are you sure the plugin is enabled, is being executed and the hook is being called ? try to add an `exit('executing...')` in the onBeforeCompileHead function just to be sure...

Comment: Well, Joomla reports it's enabled, but it does not appear to work as an exit call does not seem to work. (updated question to show this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename your index.php to bwai.php, and in xml, write

```
<filename plugin="bwai">bwai.php</filename>
```

then your class name should match the plugin name, and be PlgSystemBwai

Comment: Will test as soon as i get my machine with the Code on it :D